# How to code a complex ManyToMany in Java/Kotlin

Tags: java, mysql, kotlin

I have this relation in mysql:

[image: MySQL relation]

I really don't know how to code that relation in Kotlin or Java. For a ManyToMany in Kotlin I do it like this: https://gitlab.com/snippets/1696832, but in this case, it implies relating a ManyToMany table with another table.

I'm lost

Comment: What error do you get? Please, post the code of entities and information about error here.

Comment: Please also specify which ORM and which version you're using for this.

Comment: I haven't coded anything yet, I have no idea how to translate such table, I know about M2M but (M2M)2M? I'm using Spring's JpaRepository.